# How is the addition and multiplication defined in the polynomial ring of infinit. many variables $R[x_i,i\in \mathbb{N}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I know that if $R$ is a ring $R[x]$ can be defined and it is also a ring with the polynomial multiplication and the addition. In this way the  polynomial ring $R[x_1,...,x_n]$ over several variables can be constructed recursively with $R[x_1,...,x_n]:=R[x_1,...,x_{n-1}][x_n]$. How is the polynomial ring of infinitely many variables in the title defined?

Comment: It is defined exactly the same. Any given polynomial is only allowed to be a FINITE sum. So any calculation you do will only involve finitely many variables and finitely many terms.

Comment: What is the difference the infinitely is not noetherian but the finite one is why?

Comment: Your question in the post was only about how addition and multiplication in this ring works. You didn't ask about properties like being Noetherian.

Comment: Yes that was my next question thank you the first question is now answered

Comment: If this is your next question, please ask a *new* question and don't modify this one.